# Report viewer only displaying one record

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I currently have a report, which I pass a parameter through, but it is only displaying a single record (the first record it can find) for the parameter.

Query in my dataset:

```
SELECT CID, HID, Customer_Name, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Begin, Appointment_End, Room_No, RoomType, Discount FROM Appointment WHERE Appointment_Date = ?
```

My RDLC design

[image: RDLC view]

Code:

```
private void Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection db_connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\KAZEM\Documents\Hairsalon\employees.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"))
    {
        String query = "SELECT Distinct Appointment_Date FROM Appointment";
        using (OleDbCommand db_command = new OleDbCommand(query, db_connection))
        {
            db_connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = db_command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                combo_AptDate.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void combo_AptDate_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AppointmentTableAdapter.Fill(this.hairsalonDataset.Appointment, combo_AptDate.SelectedItem.ToString());

    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem...... maybe you have only one data

Comment: No I've got more than 1 record.. but it is only showing the first record it finds

Comment: Show your C# code please.

Comment: Added. combo_aptdate is a dropdownlist

Comment: Probably, the second row in report design is not a detail row, but it should be.

Comment: How could I check if it is a detail row? and make it a detail row if it isn't?

Comment: @EidolonMK, here is the rdlc report "anatomy" that could help: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC99726.gif 
if your fields are placed in table header or group header row - your result could be single record in the report.